# How do I un-hide the Project Explorer window in my VB6 IDE?

Tags: vb6

In my VB6 IDE, I accidentally clicked Hide on the context menu of the Project Explorer window (the pane on the right side with all the files from the project).  I can't figure out how to un-hide it.

Specifically the View menu has items for viewing the Immediate Window, the Locals Window, etc., but not the Project Explorer.  Restarting the IDE didn't help.

**Edit:**

Here is my View Menu (just so you don't think I'm completely crazy):

[image: VB6 IDE View Menu]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the IDE, click View > Project Explorer.

You can also use the shortcut Ctrl-R.

**Edit:**
Interesting about your Menu Bar - I've got several more items on mine.  I imagine you've already tried this, but you can reset the Menu Bar:

- Right click the Menu Bar/Tool Bar area and click Customize... on the popup.
- On the Customize dialog, select "Menu Bar" and then click the Reset... button.

Hopefully that'll do the trick.

Comment: Ctrl-R worked, but there is no menu item for View -> Project Explorer

Comment: Yep, your trick with resetting the menu bar worked.  Thanks!  I wonder what removed those items... perhaps MZ-Tools?

Comment: @Scott Glad to hear it help -- not sure what causes it!

Answer (score 1):

I found it.  There are two buttons on the tool bar:

[image: Project Explorer and Properties Window buttons]

The left one opens the project explorer window and the right one opens the properties window.